# Why replace specific character in Column Name when Importing Excel to C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

When import Microsoft Excel file to C# (WPF), specific characters in Column Names (Column Headers) will be replaced. 
eg `!` it becomes `_`, and `.` to `#`. How to stop it?

connectionString:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="+filePath+";Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=65001;";
```

And method:

```
 public DataSet ImportExcel(string fileName)
    {
        tableList = null;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string connectionString = GetConnectionString(fileName);

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

            cmd.Connection = conn;


            // Get all Sheets in Excel File
            DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            tableList = new string[dtSheet.Rows.Count];
            // Loop through all Sheets to get data
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
            {

                string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                tableList[dtSheet.Rows.IndexOf(dr)] = sheetName;
                Console.WriteLine("TABLE_NAME: " + sheetName);
                if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                    continue;

                // Get all rows from the Sheet
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.TableName = sheetName;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                rowsCount += dt.Rows.Count;
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            }

            cmd = null;
            conn.Close();
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are limited to what characters are allowed in column names, these are letters, numbers and characters: @#$_ see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx). The $ symbol and numbers aren't allowed to be the first character either.